# Downloading a file in C# incorrectly returns files that is zero bytes long

Tags: c#, webclient

So I'm trying to Download a file using WebClient class but the problem is that when the download is finished the file that should be downloaded is 0 byte, I tried uploading the same file without extension and than changing it after download but that didn't help. What Can I do? This is the code I Use

```
WebClient updateDownloader = new WebClient();
updateDownloader.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://zazaia.ucoz.com/SomeExeFile.exe"),      
Application.StartupPath + "\\SomeFile.EXE");
```

And also have DownloadCompleted event handler which just shows MessageBox and Disposes the WebClient.

Comment: is application type console?

Comment: Have you confirmed that if you download the file, eg using FTP or browser, that it is indeed larger than 0 bytes?  Could be a problem with the server itself.

Comment: no it's a form application

Comment: I have no problem downloading it by anothing except for the WebClient Class. Everything seems to OK. May be there is some problem with server i don't know

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown and this should work. The problem is on the server which is not returning the file properly. Also make sure that the site you are querying doesn't require some authentication before being able to download files. In addition to that don't forget that a WebClient will not execute any javascript, so if the server relies on it to download the file, this will not happen.

Comment: I need to do following. I have uploaded txt file to the same ucoz website. My application should check the txt file and download the .exe file according to its content. Can I do it in another way. The only thing i need is that when i upload new exe file the direct link to the file should be the same. that's why I use ucoz.

Comment: Try downloading the file from your browser and use `Fiddler` to inspect the request and more specifically the HTTP request headers being sent. Then you could add those same headers to the `WebClient` in order to have the exact same request as the browser. So make sure that you are first able to download the file in a browser.

Comment: OK I understood what you said, but how do I add header to WebClient Class, I see that it has Headers Propery which is WebHeadersCollection type but I don't know what to add in that collection! when i copy headers from Fiddler there plenty of text which to be honest i don't really know what they mean. What should I add to the header Collection!

Comment: Sorry for my bad English !

Comment: For example if you wanted to add the UserAgent header you could use this: `client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "...";`. You should do the same for each header you want to add.

Comment: It's doing the same thing. downloaded file is just 0 bytes

Comment: Yes, it works in the browser. Any browser just downloads it withhout problems.

Comment: Then you probably forgot to add some header that the browser is sending. You could use Fiddler to compare the 2 requests. In order to be able to capture the request performed by your WebClient with Fiddler you need to instruct it to use a proxy: `client.Proxy = new WebProxy("localhost", 8888);`. Then make sure that the 2 requests send the same headers. Also you will be able to see what does the server returns in response to the request of your WebClient and whether the file is actually being sent.

Comment: I add 14 Headers out of 17. there was no definition for other 3 headers in C#

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that your antivirus is not interfering? Sometimes an automatic scan will lock an executable file being downloaded until it passes. The client code itself looks fine however.

What about the server side? If is one of your own applications serving the download, then it may not be setting the MIME header or even not handling the download correctly at all

Comment: Antivirus is disable for this moment, so i cannot interfere with download, Firewall is off as well!

Comment: @DitoQarcidze what about the server? Is that also a custom application?